# Is $f$ differentiable in $(0,0)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I need to show if $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ definied by:

$f(x,y)= \sqrt[3]{5x(x^2+y^2)}$

is differentiable in $(0,0)$.

What I already have:

$\frac{df}{dx} (0,0)=\sqrt[3]{5}$

$\frac{df}{dy} (0,0)=0$

As well as the directional derivative $\frac{df}{dv} (0,0)$ for $v = (\frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5})$:

$\frac{df}{dv} (0,0)= \sqrt[3]{3}$

But how can I show now if $f$ is differentiable in $(0,0)$ ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Knowing the partial derivatives **at** (0, 0) is not sufficient to determine whether or not the function is differentiable there.  You **can** show that by showing that the partial derivative functions are continuous in some neighborhood of (0, 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A necessary condition for differentiability is that
the directional derivative in a direction $(u,v)$ should be linear in $u$ and $v$. Your example shows that this is not the case (if so $D_v f(0,0)$ should equal $3/5 \sqrt[3]{5}$).

Comment: Thank you. So I can say that because of the fact that the directional derivative here is not linear, our function is not differentiable in (0,0)?

Comment: Yes, that's the conclusion

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is differentiable at $(0,0) \iff$

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-f_x(0,0)x-f_y(0,0)y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$

Comment: Ok. So I have  
$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sqrt[3]{5x(x^2+y^2)}-0-\sqrt[3]{5}x-0y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{5}\sqrt[3]{x\left(x^2+y^2\right)}-\sqrt[3]{5}x\right)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: @PhysX Now you need to prove this limit does not exist, and conclude that $f$ is not differentiable in $(0,0).$