# Check if $\frac{x^3+y^3}{|x|+|y|}$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, differential

We have the function $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^3+y^3}{|x|+|y|},& (x, y) \ne (0,0) \\
0, &   (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}$$

My work so far:

I tried checking if $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$:

When $x >0, y>0:$

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} f(x) = \frac{(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)}{x+y} = 0$$

When $x >0, y<0:$ we can rewrite $y$ as $-y$, with $y>0$

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} f(x) = \frac{x^3-y^3}{x+y}$

Which I can not solve.

I calculated the partial derivatives:

\begin{align*}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}(0,0)&=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x} =\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{x^3}{|x|}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x^2 \mathrm{sgn}(x)= 0\\
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}(x,y)&=\frac{3x^2(|x|+|y|)-(x^3+y^3)\mathrm{sgn}(x)}{(|x|+|y|)^2}
\end{align*}

and analogously for $y$.

I tried checking if the partial derivatives are continuous and failed.

I tried with the definition:

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-T(0,0)}{||(x,y)||} = 0,$$
 where $T(x,y) = 0$.

we get $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{x^3+y^3}{(|x|+|y|)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

And I got stuck here.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363789/is-f-differentiable-in-0-0

Comment: Try polar coordinates to check if it satisfies the Frechet  condition for differentiability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the partial derivatives exist at $(0,0)$ and they are both equal to $0$. Therefore either $f$ is *not* differentiable at $(0,0)$, or it *is* differentibale there and its derivative there is the null function.

And what actually occurs is that $f'(0,0)$ is the null function. In fact, if $\varphi\colon\mathbb R^2\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is the null function, then\begin{align}f'(0,0)=\varphi&\iff\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\bigl\lvert f(x,y)-f(0,0)-\varphi(x-0,y-0)\bigr\rvert}{\bigl\lVert(x,y)\bigr\rVert}=0\\&\iff\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\lvert x^3+y^3\rvert}{\bigl(\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert\bigr)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0.\end{align}But, if $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, then$$\lvert x^3+y^3\rvert\leqslant2r^3$$and$$\bigl(\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert\bigr)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\geqslant r^2,$$since $\lvert\cos\theta\rvert+\lvert\sin\theta\rvert\geqslant\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$. Therefore,$$\frac{\lvert x^3+y^3\rvert}{\bigl(\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert\bigr)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leqslant r\to_{r\to0}0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using your calculation for the partial derivative, if we can show that this is continuous then the function is $C^1$ and thus the derivative exists at $(0,0$). Thus we need to show that:

$$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}(x,y)=\frac{3x^2(|x|+|y|)-(x^3+y^3)\mathrm{sgn}(x)}{(|x|+|y|)^2}$$

Note that we just want to ensure this is continuous around $(0,0)$. When $y=0$, this is equivalent to

$$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}\biggr\rvert_{0,0}=\frac{3x^2|x|-(x^3)\mathrm{sgn}(x)}{x^2}=\frac{3x\mathrm{sgn}(x)-x\mathrm{sgn}(x)}{x^2}$$

the absolute value of which is at most $\frac{2}{x}$ which converges to $0$. Thus since both partial derivatives are continuous at $(0,0)$ (because, as you noted, the $y$ case is equivalent), the function is differentiable there.

Comment: It is not enough to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,0) = 0$. It is a weaker condition than $ \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y) = 0$.

Comment: it is if both the x and y derivatives have continuous derivatives, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness

Comment: IF the derivatives are smooth, then both of these limits are equal, true. But you need to show the stronger consition to prove that they are smooth; the first is not enough.

Comment: Um no, if df/dx and dy/dx exist and are continuous at any point (a,b) then f is differentiable at (a,b). Period. That's literally the theorem.

Comment: Yes, but it's $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$ that need to be continuous, not just $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,b)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,y)$. And the definition of conitinuity in these cases involves $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}$.